# Dickens' or Dickens's?

Tags: apostrophe

This BBC report ([link](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-40878110)) suggests that we should use "Dickens' Great Expectations", but I remember there is a rule from Strunk and White ([here](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html)) that would suggest "Dickens's Great Expectations".

Is this just a difference due to British English vs American English?

BBC's report:

> Armagh, Banbridge and Craigavon Borough Council's grammatical error
>   appeared on an advert for a performance of Charles Dickens' Great
>   Expectations in July.

Strunk and White

> Form the possessive singular of nouns with 's.
>
> Follow this rule whatever the final consonant. Thus write,

```
Charles's friend 
Burns's poems
the witch's malice
```

> This is the usage of the
>   United States Government Printing Office and of the Oxford University
>   Press.   Exceptions are the possessives of ancient proper names in -es
>   and -is, the possessive Jesus', and such forms as for conscience'
>   sake, for righteousness' sake. ...

Comment: This is a matter of style; there is no single right or wrong answer, and it is not dependent primarily on locale. AP style, American, dictates *Dickens'*. APA style, also American, dictates *Dickens's*. And CMOS, again American, prefers *DIckens's* but has no objection to *Dickens'*. Of related interest: *[When did it become correct to add an “s” to a singular possessive already ending in “‑s”?](/q/2964)* and *[Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](/q/79081/)* among others.

Comment: There are no grammar rules governing punctuation, only house rules.

Comment: If you really want to be confused consider the spelling and pronunciation of The Court of Saint James's,  a double layer possessive with the possessive s of the second layer possessive pronounced in contravention of the 'rule' that possessive esses attached to words ending in s are silent. As it's the name of a royal court it must be part of the Queen's English but...