# What is the genitive of POTUS?

Tags: saxon-genitive

Is the genitive of [POTUS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/POTUS)

POTUS'

or

POTUS's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s) Also [Strunk and White says “Charles's” is correct — is this still the case?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62257/), and [Dickens' or Dickens's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405428/dickens-or-dickenss)

Comment: Why use that acronym (as opposed to 'President')?